# Make Ascii buildings with arguments

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Make 2d ASCII buildings depending on what the input is. The submissions can either be a program that takes input, or a function that accepts input via its parameters.

e.g. An input of `5,3,6` would output

```
          ┌──┐
          │┌┐│
┌──┐      │└┘│
│┌┐│      │┌┐│
│└┘│      │└┘│
│┌┐│      │┌┐│
│└┘│ ┌──┐ │└┘│
│┌┐│ │┌┐│ │┌┐│
│└┘│ │└┘│ │└┘│ 
│┌┐│ │┌┐│ │┌┐│
│└┘│ │└┘│ │└┘│
│┌┐│ │┌┐│ │┌┐│
│└┘│ │└┘│ │└┘│
```

and `4,2` would output

```
┌──┐
│┌┐│ 
│└┘│
│┌┐│
│└┘│ ┌──┐
│┌┐│ │┌┐│
│└┘│ │└┘│
│┌┐│ │┌┐│
│└┘│ │└┘│
```

The input can either be a string that contains the integers separated by a comma, or it can be a sequence of integers, or as an array of integers, or any other similar way. The integers will have a maximum value of 255 and they will not be negative or equal to `0`. [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Trailing spaces and newlines allowed.

### Copy and paste items

- Building Top: `┌──┐`
- Window Top: `│┌┐│`
- Window Bottom: `│└┘│`

(my first golf, hope it's not too bad)

EDIT: Turns out box drawing isn't ascii, but they seem to print in textmode, so that's okay. This is different because of the varying height and caps

EDIT 2: <s>standard input is okay, too if commandline arguments are bad (something like python's `input()`)</s>

EDIT 3: The program can either be a program or a function. In the case of a program, it should take input via STDIN or similar if it is not possible in your language. In the case of a function, the input will be passed as parameters.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the program with the shortest byte count wins!

Comment: It's not ASCII art if it requires non-ASCII characters (like the box drawing characters). Also, it's close enough to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65213/45941) to be a duplicate in my eyes.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a nice first challenges, but here is some advice: requiring input via command-line arguments is very limiting and [frowned upon](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8065/8478) in this community. It's usually best to [stick to the default I/O methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Secondly, let me recommend [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478) for future challenges where you can get feedback for your ideas before the challenge goes live. Keep it up!

Comment: @Mego with the touching buildings and half-integer input the other one seems a lot trickier than this. (That said, there might be a closer duplicate somewhere, but I wouldn't consider that one a dupe.)

Comment: @MartinEnder I disagree. This is essentially the subset of that challenge with only integer inputs (the different characters and the spacing between the buildings doesn't change the core challenge much).

Comment: Except you can't chose to answer the subset of a challenge, such answer would be disqualified. So while I think the other challenge is more interesting, this one 1) could be more accessible to beginners 2) could allow other interesting golfing tricks by its simplicity

Comment: @Mego (I think) This is different, because the figures are different heights and are not fixed. The caps might also make a difference

Comment: The windows make a remarkable difference. This is trickier than switching between two different roofs. Sharing walls and empty ground were easy.